# Java Method Overloading Called with an Interface

Tags: java, interface, overloading

I'm sure this is elementary, but I am stumped.  The example is grossly over-simplified but boils down to the following. I have some overloaded methods in a class like so:

```
public void build(MyImplOneOfAnInterface item);
public void build(MyImplTwoOfAnInterface item);
```

I then have another method that does the following:

```
public void buildIt(MyInterface item) {
     build(item);
}
```

When I attempt to compile, I get the following error:

> cannot find symbol

This is because the JVM cannot determine the implementation of the interface at compile time so that it knows which overloaded method to call.

How can this be decided at runtime? It seems like the JVM ought to be able to figure this out.

PS: I don't want to define a method that takes the interface as the argument and then does a bunch of if/else statements using instanceof operators.

Comment: Then use the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead. No?

Comment: "cannot find symbol" sounds like a compiler error (not a runtime error from the JVM) saying that a variable or class you've specified in the code cannot be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [*double dispatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).  Have a `MyInterface.build`, which is then overloaded in your implementation classes to call the relevant method.  e.g.:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void build(Thingy t);
}

class MyImplOneOfAnInterface implements MyInterface {
    void build(Thingy t) { t.build(this); }
}

...

void buildIt(MyInterface item) {
    item.build(this);
}
```

Comment: what about using an extend? i.e., `class MyImplOneOfAnInterface extends My Interface`. sounds it would be better?

Comment: This is *simulated* double dispatch, and is an application of the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  The fact is, Java can't do true double dispatch.

Comment: @Kit Ho: I don't understand what you mean.  I'm assuming `MyImplOneOfAnInterface` is a concrete class.

Comment: @Kit: You can't extend an interface, and if you mean implementation inheritance via a (abstract) base class then it wouldn't work...you wouldn't be left with double dispatch but rather with the same compile error.

Comment: @Mark Peters: interface can be extended. see this article [link] http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html
I think using inheritance architecture would be better.

Comment: @Kit Ho: Why would it be better?  The OP has two concrete classes, so at some point we must `implement`.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth: well, what does OP mean? in the above question, we can define Myinterfaces as parents and MyImplOneOfAnInterface and MyImplTwoOfAnInterface as children. Then can have a better inheritance arch such that some methods can be used together through their parent

Comment: @Kit Ho: For (simulated) double-dispatch to work, each concrete class must explicitly overload the `build`.  I can't quite see what it is that you're suggesting; maybe you should post a full answer with some pseudocode?

Answer (score 3):

Place the `build()` logic within the implementation. . So instead of `build(item)` call `item.build()`.

Or take a look at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), where you can do `item.build(builder)` instead of `builder.build(item)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking the inheritance at the wrong side.

MyImplOne... and MyImplTwo are both implementations of your interface. But if you call build(item), it will expect to find

```
public void build(MyInterface item):
```

else, it may find that you pass an object that implements your interface but is neither from class MyImplOne or MyImplTwo.

Like as defining a method

```
public void print(Vector vector);
```

and hoping that the compiler can resolve

```
print(new Object());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is being passed into `void buildIt(MyInterface item)` as a `MyInterface` type. When you try to call `build(item)` it looks for a method with the signature `void build(MyInterface item)`. As you can see, this method does not exist - this is why you get a symbol not found error.